# Save data globally and access from various activity in android studio

Tags: android, constants, global-variables

How can I save data Globally in android studio. And can access it from any where like any activity/fragment.
Please help me.

Comment: Have you made a previous research? Please search on google by using the keywords: android persist data.
By doing this, I've got good answers like [this one](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Persisting-Data-to-the-Device). And please also give a look at [what are the StackOverflow on-topic answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to saving data for access across all your activities of your  android application. The solution you pick depends on your requirements but most popular approaches IMO

1. Is the data simple , primitive type - like an int, double etc?  You could use shared preferences. These preferences will be available across your app on device you have installed and get deleted on cases like Factory data reset on your device.

2)More persistent solution will be sqlite DB.

Check this for improved understanding https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage